# Using pbcopy & pbpaste with rich text formatting results in empty clipboard

Tags: command-line, copy-paste

I've found [plenty of resources](https://www.ostricher.com/2015/08/from-markdown-to-pastable-formatted-text-in-os-x-terminal/) that say this should work, but I'm having no luck with rich text formatting with the `pcopy` & `pbpaste` commands on MacOS Catalina 10.15.4.

```
% echo '**foo**' | pandoc -t rtf -s | pbcopy -pboard general -Prefer rtf
% pbpaste -pboard general -Prefer rtf
<nothing>%
```

Pasting with ⌘V doesn't work either, is empty.

Formatting information is definitely being stored somewhere though, when I copy formatted text in a google document and re-paste it somewhere else the formatting is conserved, but no matter what I do with `pbpaste` it results in plain text output.

Comment: Can you add at least one source which claims it works?

Comment: It will take rtf or eps data only if it has the requisite header.  What is the `pandoc` command?  Do you know if it’s supplying the appropriate header?

Comment: The `pbcopy` part (first) seems to work, pasting into TextEdit inserts `foo` in bold. Don't think Terminal can handle formatted text upon paste.

Comment: The linked page offers a "A simple one-liner to get from a Markdown blob, to RTF in your clipboard, ready to paste wherever you want.". This part seems to work, as long as "wherever" isn't Terminal or `pbpaste` :-)

Comment: Thanks @nohillside, that's good to know. I was testing out formatted pasting into a google document and the terminal. Still don't understand the `pbaste` output then

Comment: This just showed up in my RSS reader https://eclecticlight.co/2020/05/12/cut-copy-paste-inside-the-pasteboard-clipboard/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that TextEdit (and possibly other MacOS text editors) store `public.rtf` format to the clipboard. The `man` page for `pbpaste` implies that `rtf` alone will work, but I find that the whole `public.rtf` works while just `rtf` does not on my box (OSX 12.4).

```
pbpaste -pboard general -Prefer public.rtf | cat -e; echo
```

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf2638$
\cocoatextscaling0\cocoaplatform0{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}$
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}$
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;}$
\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0$
$
\f0\fs28 \cf0 Hello World!}
```

Comment: Wow. That's it!

Answer (score 8):

In my experience it's impossible to get RTF data out of `pbpaste`, even if the man page says otherwise.

I suggest you use [pbv](https://github.com/chbrown/macos-pasteboard) for that.

For example, after copying the following rich text string into your clipboard:

> "Hi, I'm **rich** *text*"

`pbv` is able to give you back proper RTF data:

```
$ pbv public.rtf | textutil -stdin -info
File:  stdin
  Type:  rich text format (RTF)
  Length:  19 characters
  Contents:  "Hi, I'm rich text"
```

Whereas `pbpaste` will always output plain text even when instructed to prefer RTF:

```
$ pbpaste -Prefer rtf | textutil -stdin -info
File:  stdin
  Type:  plain text
  Length:  19 characters
  Contents:  "Hi, I'm rich text"
```

Found via this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17217450/3078265).